# Teradata - How to add-list all available databases on Teradata server under SQL Assistant Query Tool?

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am using `Teradata SQL Assistant`. I am a new user to `Teradata` database.
Like in `SQL Server Management Studio`, I am not able to see the available databases on `Teradata Server` via `SQL Assistant`.

So I just wanted to ask, how can I list all the databases available on `Teradata Server` in `SQL Assitant`.
With this information only, I would be able to decide which databases I need & can ask for the required accesses.

I searched on Google & found we need to manually add databases in `SQL Assitant` which is not very helpful unless you know the database name. Are there any other tools available which will show me the available databases list in structured-ordered ways like in SSMS ?

Any information-links would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: The `dbc.DatabasesV` view shows all existing database/user names, but you might better use `dbc.DatabasesVX` instead which lists only databases where the current user has access to.

Comment: @dnoeth, But in case of database under database (hierarchical database) ? I might need a separate code to figure out those. So I am looking for a tool which will do it for me by default. Like SQL Server Management Studio...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @dnoeth mentioned, you can get a list of databases by querying the DBC.databasesV table. If you want to also see the hierarchy, you can see the OwnerName in that table and create the hierarchy from that parent/child relationship.

A way to show that hierarchy visually in SQL is using a Recursive CTE. In your case:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dbs AS
(
    SELECT 

        databasename,
        ownername,
        0 AS depth,
        cast(databasename AS VARCHAR(500)) AS path,
        CAST(DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(500)) AS pretty_hierarchy

    FROM "DBC".databasesv
    WHERE DatabaseName = 'DBC'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        dbsv.databasename,
        dbsv.ownername,
        depth + 1 AS depth,
        path || '>' || dbsv.databasename,
        substring('            ' FROM 1 FOR (dbs.depth + 1)*3) || dbsv.DatabaseName 
    FROM
        dbs INNER JOIN "DBC".DatabasesV dbsv ON
            dbsv.OwnerName = dbs.databasename AND
            dbsv.DatabaseName <> dbs.databasename
    WHERE dbs.depth <=10
)
SELECT * FROM dbs ORDER BY "path", depth
```

Comment: This is really a cool solution! Adding more, I am looking for a tool (Query tool like SQL Assistant) which will have these databases pre-added in their Database Explorer pane. Any such tool you know ?

Comment: I use atanasuite which has a nice DB explorer pane and a million extra built in tools.

Comment: I hope we need not add the databases manually in db pane with Atanasuite ? Will try if i can get this. Not sure boss whether will approve :/ Also heard about Teradata studio ... ?

Comment: thanks. Found Teradata Administrator tool which lists all the databases & user. Bit complex to understand the hierarchical structure. Please share if you have any good links to understand the hierarchical structure :)

Comment: I believe that teradata administrators days are numbered. I was going to look at studio since I have it installed but I had to update my java and was afraid I would break a different install so I stopped. Atanasuite lists all the sea plus it has a ton of built in tools for data copying, ttu integration and a bunch of other things. Maybe if they do trial licenses it might be worth checking out.

Comment: I had same issues and this helped me (from TD forum): Is the database you are looking for a child to another database? You can change the Data Source Explorer view to show all the databases in a flat view (not hierarchical) by changing a preference. Go to "Window"->"Preferences"->"Teradata Datatools"->"Data Source Explorer Load"->Uncheck the "Show Databases and Users in Hierarchical Display" option (Under "What to display"). Finally click on "Apply" button at bottom and restart Teradata Studio.
Now you should see all databases listed under "Databases" folder.
Hope this'll help someone.